# SQL Server : How to make this query more efficient/faster?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Question for the SQL Wizards & Masters out there. I've got to get the execution time down on this beast. It's taking 5+ minutes to execute and occasionally times out. I need help understanding how to make it more efficient. I'm returning about 100,000 rows.

The scenario is: I’m trying to identify “valid orders” that should be flagged for something called the "Dating season". These orders will have items associated with valid ‘category codes’ (dbo.DTITEMS ON od.CATEGORY = dbo.DTITEMS.CATEGORY).

Then I use the results of this query to basically update an order field “DTGSEASON” with the value of the current "dating season."

I reference a table called DATING (separate from CRM.Dbo.Dating) that stores parameters like Promotion Start & End Dates, current dating season, etc.

Here’s the query I’m running to find ‘Valid Orders’, called vDatingValidOrdersReg:

```
SELECT     
      h.CUSTOMER
    , h.ORDNUMBER
    , h.INVNETWTX
    , dtgseason.VALUE AS dtgseason
    , c.comp_dqdatingmin
    , dbo.DTITEMS.ALTMINIMUM
    , d.dat_datingapprovedon
    , d.dat_ordsincepromostart
    , h.EXPDATE
    , dbo.DATING.PROMOSTART
    , d.dat_season
    , d.dat_year
    , od.ITEM
    , od.CATEGORY
    , d.dat_DatingID
    , c.Comp_Name
    , d.dat_state
    , h.ORDUNIQ
    , c.comp_dqdatingmax
FROM CRM.dbo.Dating AS d 
INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.Company AS c 
    ON d.dat_CompanyId = c.Comp_CompanyId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OEORDH AS h 
    ON c.Comp_IdCust = h.CUSTOMER 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OEORDHO AS dtgseason 
    ON h.ORDUNIQ = dtgseason.ORDUNIQ AND dtgseason.OPTFIELD = 'dtgseason'
INNER JOIN dbo.OEORDD AS od 
    ON h.ORDUNIQ = od.ORDUNIQ 
INNER JOIN dbo.DTITEMS 
    ON od.CATEGORY = dbo.DTITEMS.CATEGORY 
INNER JOIN dbo.DATING 
    ON d.dat_season = dbo.DATING.SEASON 
    AND d.dat_year = dbo.DATING.YEAR 
    AND dbo.DTITEMS.SEASON = dbo.DATING.SEASON 
    AND dbo.DTITEMS.YEAR = dbo.DATING.YEAR
WHERE (h.ORDDATE BETWEEN dbo.DATING.PROMOSTART AND dbo.DATING.PROMOEND) 
    AND (h.EXPDATE BETWEEN dbo.DATING.EXPSHIPST AND dbo.DATING.EXPSHIPEND) 
    AND (d.dat_state = 'Approve') 
    AND (d.dat_Deleted IS NULL) 
    AND (dbo.DATING.SEASCLOSED = 0) 
    AND (dbo.DTITEMS.ALTMINIMUM = 0) 
    AND (h.ORDNUMBER NOT IN (
                             SELECT     ORDNUMBER
                             FROM       dbo.vDatingValidOrdersAlt)) 
    AND (dbo.DATING.ORDERON = 1)
```

Here’s the query it references, which is basically the same thing, but looks for orders with different item categories: vDatingValidOrdersAlt. Is this my problem?

```
SELECT     
    h.CUSTOMER
    , h.ORDNUMBER
    , h.INVNETWTX
    , dtgseason.VALUE AS dtgseason
    , c.comp_dqdatingmin
    , dbo.DTITEMS.ALTMINIMUM
    , d.dat_datingapprovedon
    , d.dat_ordsincepromostart
    , h.EXPDATE
    , dbo.DATING.PROMOSTART
    , d.dat_season
    , d.dat_year
    , od.ITEM
    , od.CATEGORY
    , d.dat_DatingID
    , c.Comp_Name
    , d.dat_state
    , h.ORDUNIQ, c.comp_dqdatingmax
FROM CRM.dbo.Dating AS d 
INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.Company AS c 
    ON d.dat_CompanyId = c.Comp_CompanyId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OEORDH AS h 
    ON c.Comp_IdCust = h.CUSTOMER 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OEORDHO AS dtgseason 
    ON h.ORDUNIQ = dtgseason.ORDUNIQ AND dtgseason.OPTFIELD = 'dtgseason' 
INNER JOIN dbo.OEORDD AS od 
    ON h.ORDUNIQ = od.ORDUNIQ 
INNER JOIN dbo.DTITEMS 
    ON od.CATEGORY = dbo.DTITEMS.CATEGORY 
INNER JOIN dbo.DATING 
    ON d.dat_season = dbo.DATING.SEASON 
    AND d.dat_year = dbo.DATING.YEAR 
    AND dbo.DTITEMS.SEASON = dbo.DATING.SEASON 
    AND dbo.DTITEMS.YEAR = dbo.DATING.YEAR
WHERE (h.ORDDATE BETWEEN dbo.DATING.PROMOSTART AND dbo.DATING.PROMOEND) 
    AND (h.EXPDATE BETWEEN dbo.DATING.EXPSHIPST AND dbo.DATING.EXPSHIPEND)
    AND (d.dat_state = 'Approve') 
    AND (d.dat_Deleted IS NULL) 
    AND (dbo.DATING.SEASCLOSED = 0) 
    AND (dbo.DTITEMS.ALTMINIMUM > 0) 
    AND (dbo.DATING.ORDERON = 1)
```

There must be a way to make this query less resource-intensive, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Thoughts and suggestions?

Comment: Please consider making better use of whitespace when formatting your queries. Those queries are very difficult to read, as everything is condensed onto a few lines. As the the query performances. you'll need to supply the DDL for the tables, the indexes, and also the query plan. We won't be able to tell you how to improve the query effectively without all of these.

Comment: Also, you have some `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s in your query, however, reference the object in your `WHERE` (for example `h.EXPDATE`). This implicitly turns the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`. Is this intended? If so, you should use an `INNER JOIN`, if not, you need to address your `WHERE` or `ON` clauses..

Comment: @Larnu I tried... edit: looks like Sean Lange made a formatting attempt too haha.

Comment: @JacobH it's far better than it was. Now we just need to wait for the DDL, Query plan, Index details, and why the OP is referencing objects that have a `LEFT JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause with an `OR` clause and an `IS NULL` expression; meaning it's no longer a `LEFT JOIN`. Quite a few questions for them to answer. :)

Comment: If that second query is the view you are selecting from in the first query, you do *not* need to return any column except the `ORDNUMBER`. That's an easy performance increase right there. I would make a secondary view that only returns the one column for your `NOT IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical issue in both of these queries. You have a left join to dbo.OEORDH but then have a where clause on that table. That is logically changing your left join to an inner join. As for performance I don't see anything glaring that you can change in your sql. I would however be surprised if you have indexes situated to cover these queries. We would need to see the table definition and indexes. Also, posting the execution plans would be crucial in figuring this out.

Here is what those two queries might look like with some formatting.

```
SELECT h.CUSTOMER
    , h.ORDNUMBER
    , h.INVNETWTX
    , dtgseason.VALUE AS dtgseason
    , c.comp_dqdatingmin
    , di.ALTMINIMUM
    , d.dat_datingapprovedon
    , d.dat_ordsincepromostart
    , h.EXPDATE
    , dd.PROMOSTART
    , d.dat_season
    , d.dat_year
    , od.ITEM
    , od.CATEGORY
    , d.dat_DatingID
    , c.Comp_Name
    , d.dat_state
    , h.ORDUNIQ
    , c.comp_dqdatingmax
FROM CRM.dbo.Dating AS d 
INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.Company AS c ON d.dat_CompanyId = c.Comp_CompanyId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OEORDH AS h ON c.Comp_IdCust = h.CUSTOMER 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OEORDHO AS dtgseason ON h.ORDUNIQ = dtgseason.ORDUNIQ 
                                        AND dtgseason.OPTFIELD = 'dtgseason' 
INNER JOIN dbo.OEORDD AS od ON h.ORDUNIQ = od.ORDUNIQ 
INNER JOIN dbo.DTITEMS di ON od.CATEGORY = di.CATEGORY 
INNER JOIN dbo.DATING dd ON d.dat_season = dd.SEASON 
                        AND d.dat_year = dd.YEAR 
                        AND di.SEASON = dd.SEASON 
                        AND di.YEAR = dd.YEAR
WHERE h.ORDDATE BETWEEN dd.PROMOSTART AND dd.PROMOEND
    AND h.EXPDATE BETWEEN dd.EXPSHIPST AND dd.EXPSHIPEND
    AND d.dat_state = 'Approve'
    AND d.dat_Deleted IS NULL
    AND dd.SEASCLOSED = 0
    AND di.ALTMINIMUM = 0
    AND h.ORDNUMBER NOT IN (SELECT ORDNUMBER FROM dbo.vDatingValidOrdersAlt)
    AND dd.ORDERON = 1
```

And the second one.

```
SELECT h.CUSTOMER
    , h.ORDNUMBER
    , h.INVNETWTX
    , dtgseason.VALUE AS dtgseason
    , c.comp_dqdatingmin
    , di.ALTMINIMUM
    , d.dat_datingapprovedon
    , d.dat_ordsincepromostart
    , h.EXPDATE
    , dd.PROMOSTART
    , d.dat_season
    , d.dat_year
    , od.ITEM
    , od.CATEGORY
    , d.dat_DatingID
    , c.Comp_Name
    , d.dat_state
    , h.ORDUNIQ
    , c.comp_dqdatingmax
FROM CRM.dbo.Dating AS d 
INNER JOIN CRM.dbo.Company AS c ON d.dat_CompanyId = c.Comp_CompanyId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OEORDH AS h ON c.Comp_IdCust = h.CUSTOMER 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.OEORDHO AS dtgseason ON h.ORDUNIQ = dtgseason.ORDUNIQ 
                                        AND dtgseason.OPTFIELD = 'dtgseason' 
INNER JOIN dbo.OEORDD AS od ON h.ORDUNIQ = od.ORDUNIQ 
INNER JOIN dbo.DTITEMS as di ON od.CATEGORY = di.CATEGORY 
INNER JOIN dbo.DATING as dd ON d.dat_season = dd.SEASON 
                            AND d.dat_year = dd.YEAR 
                            AND di.SEASON = dd.SEASON 
                            AND di.YEAR = dd.YEAR
WHERE h.ORDDATE BETWEEN dd.PROMOSTART AND dd.PROMOEND
    AND h.EXPDATE BETWEEN dd.EXPSHIPST AND dd.EXPSHIPEND
    AND d.dat_state = 'Approve'
    AND d.dat_Deleted IS NULL
    AND dd.SEASCLOSED = 0
    AND di.ALTMINIMUM > 0
    AND dd.ORDERON = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for everything so far. Sounds like I need to change the LEFT OUTER join to OEORDH to an INNER join, and update the vDatingValidOrdersAlt view to only return the ORDNUMBER value. I have the estimated execution plan but it was too long to paste here as XML- is there a better way to show it?

Comment: @SQLLearner Have a Google of "Paste the Plan"